# $S_k$ action on $A/I$

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, invariant-theory, invariance

Let $S_2$ be a finite group of order $2$ and let $S_2$ act on $k[x,y]$ by interchanging $x$ and $y$, where $k=\overline{k}$. Then since

$$
R = \left( \dfrac{k[x,y]}{(x+y)}
\right)^{S_2} 
= \dfrac{k[x+y,xy]}{(x+y)} \cong k[xy], 
$$

$\mbox{Spec} \;R =k$.

On the other hand,

$$
Q  = \left( \dfrac{k[x,y]}{(x-y)}
\right)^{S_2} 
= \dfrac{k[x+y,xy]}{(x-y)}. 
$$

> Can we simplify $Q$ further as in the first example, and isn't $\mbox{Spec}\; Q$  isomorphic to a line?
>
> $\mathbf{Remark}:$ the $S_2$ invariant functions on $k[x,y]/(x+y)$ is certainly $k[xy]$  (the entire line is $S_2$-invariant) but I don't think the RHS of $Q$ 
>   is correct: the $S_2$-invariant functions on the line defined by $k[x,y]/(x-y)$ should really be a point.  Don't you agree?

$
\mathbf{General \; case:} 
$
Let $A=k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ and let $I$ be an ideal of $A$. Give some action of  $S_k$ on $A$. Then do we have 
$$ 
\left( \dfrac{A}{I} \right)^{S_k} =  \dfrac{A^{S_k} }{I} 
$$ 
or is it 
$$ 
\left( \dfrac{A}{I} \right)^{S_k} =  \dfrac{A^{S_k} }{IA^{S_k}}?  
$$

$$
$$

Comment: I am guessing that one can consider $$0\rightarrow I \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/I\rightarrow 0$$ and then take the $S_2$-invariant pieces: $$0\rightarrow I^{S_k} \rightarrow A^{S_k} \rightarrow \left( A/I\right)^{S_k}\rightarrow 0.$$ Is exactness still preserved in the second short exact sequence?

Comment: I'm not familiar with everything in this question, but don't we have $x+y\equiv 2x\bmod x-y$ hence $$\frac{k[x+y,xy]}{(x-y)}\cong k[x]~?$$

Comment: Hi anon, that may possibly be true but geometrically speaking (trying to make sense of this both geometrically and algebraically), I am not certain at the moment...

Comment: You might be doing something wrong: quotienting out $x-y$ means $S_2$ acts *trivially*, since $x=y$ in such a ring! In general, taking the invariant subalgebra of a group action is left exact, but not right exact (that way $\Ext$ groups lie...).

Comment: So are you saying that $$Q  = \left( \dfrac{k[x,y]}{(x-y)}
\right)^{S_2} 
= \dfrac{k[x,y]}{(x-y)}$$ since $x=y$ in this ring?

Comment: In $k[x,y]/(x+y)$, we have the identity $x= -y$. So  $k[x,y]/(x+y)\cong k[-y,y]$. Since $S_2$ takes $-y$ to $y$ (and sort of sketching the real picture), it's seems that $k[-y,y]^{S_2}$ is the closed half of the real line. $$ $$ Or should one think of $k[-y,y]=k[y]$, which implies $k[y]^{S_2} = k[y]$?

Comment: You are confusing isomorphism and equality.  Your first comment above about $Q$ is correct.  Now $k[x,y]/(x+y)$ is indeed just $k[y]$; but $S_2$ acts by sending $y$ to $-y$; thus the fixed points are $k[y^2]\subset k[y]$.  This is *isomorphic* to $k[y]$, but they are not equal.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Steve!